# django-rest-framework quickstart: login into its API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have setuped django-rest-framework and its basic users/groups api as described here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/. While I can see users and groups via the api, I can't log in. There is /api-auth/login page and whenever I insert un & passwd and submit it just redirects to the same page without any renderred message. I wonder what I am missing. How can I "log in" into the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by me employing a custom auth backend:

```
# settings.py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'web.auth_backends.EmailAuthBackend',
)

# auth_backends.py
class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Basically it was being passed a keyword "username" but it accepted "email" instead. So it raised an exception that was catched in django's contrib.auth.authentificate and user was not able to log in. I solved it by substituting "email" for "username".

Comment: Remember to mark this as answer if you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Django rest framework support different methods of authentification. Not sure what you mean by /api-auth/. There is no such standard url in this framework. Please check [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication) to see what methods of authentication are possible and how to do it.

Comment: If you go on the provided link in the question and search for 'api-auth', you will find out what I meant. Anyway it was my fault that I incorrectly replaced Authentication backend for my own.

Comment: Well i did the search. There is no api-auth on the link i provided. As well as there is no api-auth in the source code of django-rest-framework ( that what i was checked in first place)

Comment: well that is strange, this is the url http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ and I can locate this paragraph: _If you're intending to use the browsable API you'll probably also want to add REST framework's login and logout views. Add the following to your root urls.py file._

`urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
)`

Comment: Well, its main page not my link. And its just example of url, not something that coded into framework, so it can by anything.